# How to selectively [double] insert (T-SQL) using a single command?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is a question for a SQL expert. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

I have two relevant tables: `Labs` and `LabUsers`.

Users are assigned to Labs with no repetitions of an entire groups of any order.

The goal is to insert a `@userName` (for the example `@user = "Paul"`) into `LabUsers` fulfilling all the following limitations:

1. No more than `@maxUsers` in a group (for the example `@maxUsers=4`)
2. No duplicates of **complete** groups (full labs). The order of the users in a group is not significant. **[edited]**
3. If no existing Lab is allowed, create (`INSERT`) a new lab, then insert the row for `@user`, given no exceeding `@maxLabs` (for the example `@maxLabs=5`).
4. **Very important**: There are many concurrent same requests from the server in a split of a second, which may interfere one to the other. Therefore, as soon as the command begins to execute, no other queries are allowed to execute until the end of this command.
5. The query should return 0 in cases it cannot meet the above restrictions, and return the `LabID` of the inserted row.
6. **[EDITED]** There are several Labs' zones. The zones are independent. Each zone #labCount is bounded by the `@maxLabs`. The `@maxLabs` is equal for all zones, therefore the `Total_maxLabs` = `@maxLabs` x `#zonesCount` . For the example `@zone=51` (later on `@zone=52, 53 etc.`). (The same LabUsers can use zones with no limitations. Zones do not 'know' about each other)
7. `LabID` in `LabUsers` is a foreign key from `Labs`.

The example:

Here is the `Labs` table:

```
LabID   LabName     LabZone
-----   -------     -------
1       North       51  
2       North East  51
3       South West  51
```

And the `LabUsers` is:

```
LabUserID   LabUserName LabID
---------   ----------- -----
1           Diana       3
2           Julia       2
3           Paula       2
4           Romeo       1
5           Julia       3
6           Rose        2
7           Diana       1
8           Diana       2
9           Julia       1
10          Romeo       3
11          Paul        1
```

In the example the users are assigned like this:

```
LabID   LabName     LabZone LabUsers (ordered LTR a>z)
-----   -------     ------- --------
1       North       51      Diana•Julia•Paul•Romeo
2       North East  51      Diana•Julia•Paula•Rose
3       South West  51      Diana•Julia•Romeo
```

- The insert should not be into `LabID=1` or 2 because there are already 4 users in these labs.
- The insert should not take place into `LabID=3` due to creating duplicate with `LabID=1`.

Therefore, because the `@maxLabs` is not 3 (existing labs), it is necessary to insert a new row into `Labs` with the value `LabZone=@zone=51`.

The `IDENTITY` will set the `LabID` to 4 for the new row.

Now is the time to insert `Paul` into `LabUsers` with `LabID` just returned from inserting a new lab.

How to solve this problem?

What is the method to use in order to ensure that the command is executed as a whole with no interference?

The script to create the database is:

```
CREATE DATABASE [Allocation]
GO

USE [Allocation]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LabUsers](
    [LabUserID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ,
    [LabUserName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LabID] [int] NOT NULL)
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] ON
INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] ([LabUserID], [LabUserName], [LabID]) VALUES (1, N'Diana', 3)
INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] ([LabUserID], [LabUserName], [LabID]) VALUES (2, N'Julia', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] ([LabUserID], [LabUserName], [LabID]) VALUES (3, N'Paula', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] ([LabUserID], [LabUserName], [LabID]) VALUES (4, N'Romeo', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] ([LabUserID], [LabUserName], [LabID]) VALUES (5, N'Julia', 3)
INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] ([LabUserID], [LabUserName], [LabID]) VALUES (6, N'Rose', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] ([LabUserID], [LabUserName], [LabID]) VALUES (7, N'Diana', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] ([LabUserID], [LabUserName], [LabID]) VALUES (8, N'Diana', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] ([LabUserID], [LabUserName], [LabID]) VALUES (9, N'Julia', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] ([LabUserID], [LabUserName], [LabID]) VALUES (10, N'Romeo', 3)
INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] ([LabUserID], [LabUserName], [LabID]) VALUES (11, N'Paul', 1)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[LabUsers] OFF

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Labs](
    [LabID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ,
    [LabName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [LabZone] [int] NOT NULL)
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Labs] ON
INSERT [dbo].[Labs] ([LabID], [LabName], [LabZone]) VALUES (1, N'North', 51)
INSERT [dbo].[Labs] ([LabID], [LabName], [LabZone]) VALUES (2, N'North East', 51)
INSERT [dbo].[Labs] ([LabID], [LabName], [LabZone]) VALUES (3, N'South West', 51)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Labs] OFF
```

Comment: I tried several queries one after another with the conditions in my external code. It works when one concurrent user is online, but there is a problem with more.

Comment: While not many of us may consider themselves experts without too much immodesty, no-one is really immune to a stroke of genius at one time or the other. Therefore, you might consider editing your question with what you've tried, just so none of us, experts or not, attempts to try ways that might have already lead you to stepping on a rake or two. On the other hand, it may also appear that your attempts were in the right direction and merely missing a final stroke.

Comment: Looks to me like a `MERGE` command with `OUTPUT` clause and a table hint, but couldn't figure out.

Comment: @dradu: It might be possible to come up with a MERGE statement inserting one or zero rows into `Labs` and OUTPUTting the correct `LabID` into `LabUsers`, but `LabUsers` has (must have had) a foreign key and cannot be OUTPUT into. So, this seems to have to be more than a single MERGE.

Comment: @Andriy M: Good observation, upvoting comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I piggy backed off dradu's variables and implemented a similar but different solution.  It does make the assumption that a new lab will be 1 more than the maximum available current lab.  I also make the assumption a lab does NOT remove users.

The goal of this solution is to see what the end result of insertion of the user would look like and run checks on it to see which end result is valid.  The logic is as follows:

1. Get available labs to insert into

   - Check to make sure user not in lab here
   - Check to make sure lab not full here
   - Include new lab possibility here as well
2. Create a list of all lab users per lab sorted alphabetically if the lab will be full after the user is inserted

   - the new possible labs are flagged
3. Compare the flagged lab lists vs the unflagged lab lists and choose the minimum labId that isn't a duplicate of an existing full lab list
4. Return LabId inserted into or 0 as output

Given the starting data from the original question and execution in the order below:

1. Insert @userName = "Paul", @labZone = 51

   - Paul gets added to the newly created Lab 4
2. Insert @userName = "Paul", @labZone = 51

   - Paul gets added to the newly created Lab 5
3. Insert @userName = "Paul", @labZone = 51

   - No more new labs and no existing labs for Paul to go to so return 0
4. Insert @userName = "Rose", @labZone = 51

   - Rose gets added to the existing Lab 3
5. Insert @userName = "Rose", @labZone = 51

   - Rose gets added to the existing Lab 4
6. Insert @userName = "Rose", @labZone = 51

   - Rose gets added to the existing Lab 5

A tablockx within the transaction on LabUsers should prevent concurrent transactions from causing havoc.

Also, when debugging common table expressions, it helps to replace them with a temporary table so you can look at the results of each step along the way.

```
BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @maxUsers INT
DECLARE @maxLabs INT
DECLARE @userName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @labZone INT
DECLARE @labID INT

SET @maxUsers = 4
SET @maxLabs = 5

SET @userName = 'Paul'
SET @labZone = 52
SET @labID = NULL

declare @currentLabCount int

-- get current number of labs
select @currentLabCount = count(*)
from Labs l
/*
-- uncomment this if the max labs applies individual lab zones rather than across all lab zones
where LabZone = @labZone
*/  

;with availableLabs as ( -- get available labs to insert into
    -- check existing labs for valid spots
    select
        lu.LabID
    ,   count(*) + 1 as LabUserCount -- need this to see when we're at max users
    from LabUsers lu with (tablockx) -- ensures blocking until this completes (serialization)
      inner join Labs l with (tablockx) -- might as well lock this too
        on l.LabId = lu.LabID
        and l.LabZone = @labZone -- check Lab Zone
    where not exists( -- make sure lab user isn't already in this lab
        select 1
        from LabUsers lu2
        where lu2.LabId = lu.LabId
        and lu2.LabUserName = @userName
    )
    group by lu.LabID
    having count(*) < @maxUsers -- make sure lab isn't full
    union all
    -- create new lab if not at limit
    select
        max(LabId) + 1 as LabId
    ,   1 as LabUserCount
    from Labs -- check all labs
    where @currentLabCount < @maxLabs -- don't bother checking new labs if going to exceed max allowable labs
)
-- only do this check if lab is going to be filled
, dupeCheck as( -- generates a lab user list sorted alphabetically by lab user name per lab
    select
        y.LabId
    ,   max(y.newLabFlag) as newLabFlag -- if existing lab getting new lab user, then 1, if new lab with new lab user, then 1 else 0
    ,   replace(replace(replace(stuff( -- cool way to comma concatenate without looping/recursion taking advantage of "XML path"
            (
                select
                    ',' + x.LabUserName + '' -- lab users
                from (
                    select
                        LabId
                    ,   @userName as LabUserName 
                    from availableLabs -- the new user and his/her potential labs
                    union all
                    select
                        lu.LabId
                    ,   lu.LabUserName
                    from LabUsers lu -- the current lab users and the labs they belong to
                ) x
                where x.LabID = y.LabId -- make sure the LabId's match
                and max(y.LabUserCount) = @maxUsers -- don't generate this list if lab is not full
                order by x.LabUserName -- sorted alphabetically
                for xml path('')
            ), 1, 1, ''
        )
        , '&lt;', '<'), '&gt;', '>'), '&amp;', '&') as LabUserList
    from (
        -- get list of old labs and flag them as such
        select
            lu.LabId
        ,   convert(tinyint,0) as newLabFlag
        ,   count(*) as LabUserCount -- need the current lab user count
        from LabUsers lu
        /*
            -- uncomment this if full labs can be duplicated across lab zones
            inner join Labs l
                on l.LabId = lu.LabId
                and l.LabZone = @labZone
        */
        group by lu.LabId
        union all
        -- get list of potential candidate labs for lab user and flag them as such
        select
            al.LabId
        ,   convert(tinyint,1) as newLabFlag
        ,   al.LabUserCount -- new lab user count if we were to insert the new user
        from availableLabs al
    ) y
    group by y.LabId
)
select
    @labID = min(dc.LabID)
from dupeCheck dc
where dc.newLabFlag = 1
-- make sure the same list of users does not already exist at an existing lab
and not exists(
    select 1
    from dupeCheck dupe
    where dupe.LabUserList = dc.LabUserList
    and dupe.newLabFlag = 0
)

-- insert new lab if doesn't exist
insert into Labs(LabName, LabZone) -- always better to be clearer
select
    'New Lab' as LabName
,   @labZone as LabZone
where @currentLabCount < @maxLabs -- make sure we can't have more than max labs
and not exists(
    select 1
    from Labs
    where LabId = @labId
)

-- insert lab users
insert into LabUsers(LabUserName, LabId)
select
    @userName as LabUserName
,   @labId as LabId
where @labId is not null

-- return labId
select isnull(@labId,0)
commit tran
```

Comment: Zhenny- Where do you block a user from creating a lab which does not physically exist (but has mo record yet)? (the procedure keep adding labs despite the @maxLabs limit). Now, let Rose make a call to the stored procedure too. Why the procedure do not let her join to the lab no. 3 or even to the new lab Pual's call created? As last question, why not to lock Labs table too? Let say Rose, Julia and Kora called the procedure 1 millisecond before or after Paul. One caller or more may make calculations based on a changed Lab table, right?

Comment: I forgot about the @maxLabs limit.  I've edited to address this issue.  When I tested with Rose, she get's added to Lab 3 correctly and then added to Paul's new lab if run after that.  As for not locking the Labs table, I operated under the assumption that Labs would not be modified by other processes independently from LabUsers.  This script successfully blocks any requests to read or modify LabUsers until it finishes.

Comment: I'm afraid I missed a word in limitation #2. I should have wrote: No duplicates of COMPLETE groups, which means there is no reason to test for duplicity of labs which are not going to be full. The problem is Paul cannot create the the 5th Lab now with no good reason (he is not the one who will create the duplicity of complete groups). Will it be a big change let Paul create the new lab, if he is not the last one to be added to it? (I have to admit that it is hard for me to follow the code with the minimal remarks and fix it by myself)

Comment: It wasn't a big change.  I've commented the code better to better explain what it's doing.  To understand it better, take out the CTE's and break it out into each individual part (you can use temp tables, only reason I didn't was due to having to do writes to the database which hurts performance).  Also, to clarify, now the behavior changed a little which I put in the logic outline.

Comment: Yeh, I can see that, sorry. I've check it for Paul and for Rose as written, even tried them in turns, enlarged the number of max Labs, enlarged the number of max LabUsers and it works like a charm!  When changed to @labZone=52  it didn't :(

Comment: Thanks to your documentation I'm trying to overcome that by adding INNER JOINs and to extend WHEREs to include Labs.LabZone=@labZone. I've change line 30 to: from LabUsers lu2 INNER JOIN Labs ON (lu2.LabID=Labs.LabID) , and line 32 to: and lu2.LabUserName = @userName AND Labs.LabZone=@labZone . after changing lines 41+42 in a similar way I had to change line 39 to: max(LabUsers.LabId) + 1 as LabId . I did the same in lines 62 and 77, thinking this will be enough, but I was wrong. I'm still trying to solve this. If you can direct me (or fix that) it will be marvelous. THANKS.

Comment: Oops.  Not sure how I keep missing criteria!  I've added a check for Lab Zones.  If full labs can be the same across multiple lab zones, you can uncomment lines 85-90.  Otherwise, it assumes we can't have another matching complete lab with the same lab users regardless of lab zone.  You shouldn't need to change lines 41+42 since that will be a new lab regardless of zone.  Also, if max labs is unique to lab zone, you can uncomment lines 21-24.

Comment: @Zhenny- Although Andriy M gave here a solution that work from first try, I think the criterion was not clear as it should. I've updated the relevant criterion description. After uncommenting the suggested lines and making the following minor changes it works: Line 20: `from Labs l WHERE LabZone=@labZone` Line 49: `where @currentLabCount < @maxLabs AND LabZone=@labZone` Line 113: `DECLARE @tempID INT; SET @tempID= @@IDENTITY` Line 125: `IF @tempID <> @@IDENTITY SET @labId = @@IDENTITY`. Now I have to test the code against multiple concurrent users. Many thanks for the help and more for lesson.

Answer (score 0):

Since `MERGE` cannot be used, several statements are required. I couldn't come up with a simpler solution, sorry. I'm sure an expert can find a better solution.

First, I have looked for potential Labs based on the specified rules. To avoid duplicate groups, I have compared the users for each lab before and after possible inserts. If any lab is available, insert the user. If not, insert the lab, then insert the user. To lock the tables until the transaction completes, I use `isolation level serializable`. Here is the code:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE -- Range locks until transaction completes

BEGIN TRAN

DECLARE @maxUsers INT
DECLARE @maxLabs INT
DECLARE @userName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @labZone INT
DECLARE @labID INT

SET @maxUsers = 4
SET @maxLabs = 5

SET @userName = 'Paul'
SET @labZone = 51
SET @labID = NULL

--Check potential spots
;WITH U1(LabID, UserName) AS(
    SELECT LabID, LabUserName FROM dbo.LabUsers WHERE LabID IN (
        SELECT LabID 
        FROM dbo.LabUsers 
        WHERE LabUserName <> @userName 
        GROUP BY LabID 
        HAVING COUNT(LabUserName) < @maxUsers
    )
)
, U2(LabID, UserName) AS(
    SELECT LabID, LabUserName FROM dbo.LabUsers WHERE LabID IN (
        SELECT LabID 
        FROM dbo.LabUsers 
        GROUP BY LabID 
        HAVING COUNT(LabUserName) = @maxUsers
    )
)
--Get the first potential LabID
SELECT @labID = (
SELECT TOP 1 potential.LabID FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT LabID, SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' + UserName FROM (
    SELECT LabID, UserName FROM U1
    UNION SELECT LabID, @userName FROM U1
) t WHERE LabID = lu.LabID ORDER BY UserName FOR XML PATH('')
), 2, 50) AS AfterUsers, SUBSTRING((SELECT ',|' + UserName + '|' FROM (
    SELECT LabID, UserName FROM U1
) t WHERE LabID = lu.LabID ORDER BY UserName FOR XML PATH('')
), 2, 50) AS BeforeUsers
FROM U1 lu) potential
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT LabID, SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' + UserName FROM (
    SELECT LabID, UserName FROM U2
    UNION SELECT LabID, @userName FROM U2
) t WHERE LabID = lu.LabID ORDER BY UserName FOR XML PATH('')
), 2, 50) AS Users
FROM U2 lu) allocated
     ON potential.AfterUsers = allocated.Users
WHERE allocated.Users IS NULL 
    AND potential.BeforeUsers NOT LIKE '%|' + @userName + '|%'
ORDER BY 1
)

IF @labID IS NULL --No existing lab available
BEGIN

    --Insert Lab
    INSERT INTO dbo.Labs(LabName, LabZone) 
        SELECT 'New Lab', @labZone 
        WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Labs) < @maxLabs
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @labID = SCOPE_IDENTITY() --Get the new LabID
        --Insert Lab user
        INSERT INTO dbo.LabUsers(LabUserName, LabID) 
            SELECT @userName, @labID
    END

END
ELSE --Lab exists, insert user if possible
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.LabUsers(LabUserName, LabID) 
        SELECT @userName, @labID
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.LabUsers WHERE LabID = @labID AND LabUserName = @userName)

END

--A quick select to check the results
SELECT * FROM dbo.Labs
SELECT DISTINCT LabID, SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' + LabUserName FROM (
    SELECT LabID, LabUserName FROM dbo.LabUsers
) t WHERE LabID = lu.LabID ORDER BY LabUserName FOR XML PATH('')
), 2, 50) AS Users
FROM dbo.LabUsers lu

COMMIT TRAN

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED --Restore isolation level to default
```

Comment: My apologises are probably due, for it seem like my comment have mislead you. I didn't mean to imply that MERGE was inapplicable *at all*. I thought you were thinking about a solution with a *single MERGE* and I meant to demonstrate how it could not be done that way. But MERGE, and with OUTPUT too, might still be useful in solving this problem, it's just that you'd likely need to OUTPUT into something else (a temp. table or a table variable), then, I guess, use the results in an INSERT statement to add a row to the other table. Sorry again, I should have taken more care when expressing myself.

Comment: No need to apologise, your comment was correct, because initially I was thinking of one `MERGE` command only, not realising that the `OUTPUT` clause would have failed for `LabUsers`. I have to admit, but don't tell anyone, I didn't know about this `OUTPUT` constraint :)

Comment: Your secret is safe with me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt at solving this using [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx). As part of the job, this solution builds ordered CSV-lists and compares them, and so may turn out not very efficient. Nevertheless, in my tests it seems to have fulfilled all the other requirements.

First, the schema, completed with the example from the original post:

```
CREATE TABLE Labs
    (LabID int IDENTITY, LabName varchar(50), LabZone int);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Labs ON;
INSERT INTO Labs
    (LabID, LabName, LabZone)
VALUES
    (1, 'North'     , 51),
    (2, 'North East', 51),
    (3, 'South West', 51);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Labs OFF;

CREATE TABLE LabUsers
    (LabUserID int IDENTITY, LabUserName varchar(50), LabID int);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT LabUsers ON;
INSERT INTO LabUsers
    (LabUserID, LabUserName, LabID)
VALUES
    ( 1, 'Diana', 3),
    ( 2, 'Julia', 2),
    ( 3, 'Paula', 2),
    ( 4, 'Romeo', 1),
    ( 5, 'Julia', 3),
    ( 6, 'Rose' , 2),
    ( 7, 'Diana', 1),
    ( 8, 'Diana', 2),
    ( 9, 'Julia', 1),
    (10, 'Romeo', 3),
    (11, 'Paul' , 1);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT LabUsers OFF;
```

The script, commented, with parameters pre-initialised with some values:

```
/* script parameters */
DECLARE @zone     int         = 51;
DECLARE @maxLabs  int         = 3;
DECLARE @maxUsers int         = 4;
DECLARE @userName varchar(50) = 'Paul';

/* auxiliary variables */
DECLARE @defLabName varchar(50) = 'New Lab';
DECLARE @SelectedLab table (LabID int);

/* the main part begins */
WITH ZoneLabs AS (
  /* get labs for the specified @zone */
  SELECT LabID
  FROM Labs
  WHERE LabZone = @zone
)
, IncompleteLabs AS (
  /* get labs with the number of users < @maxUsers */
  SELECT LabID
  FROM LabUsers
  WHERE LabID IN (SELECT LabID FROM ZoneLabs)
  GROUP BY LabID
  HAVING COUNT(*) < @maxUsers
  UNION ALL
  /* …and add a new lab if the number of labs < @maxLabs */
  SELECT 0
  FROM ZoneLabs
  HAVING COUNT(*) < @maxLabs
)
, LabUsersAdjusted AS (
  /* get all existing users */
  SELECT LabUserID, LabUserName, LabID, 0 AS IsNew
  FROM LabUsers
  WHERE LabID IN (SELECT LabID FROM ZoneLabs)
  UNION ALL
  /* …and add the new user as a member of every incomplete lab
     unless the user is already a member */
  SELECT 0        , @userName  , LabID, 1
  FROM IncompleteLabs
  WHERE LabID NOT IN (SELECT LabID FROM LabUsers WHERE LabUserName = @userName)
)
, UsersGrouped AS (
  /* get labs along with their CSV-lists of users */
  SELECT
    LabID,
    OldUserCount = COUNT(NULLIF(IsNew, 1)),
    NewUserCount = SUM(IsNew),
    LabUsers = SUBSTRING(
      (
        SELECT ',' + LabUserName
        FROM LabUsersAdjusted
        WHERE LabID = lu.LabID
        ORDER BY LabUserName
        FOR XML PATH('')
      ),
      2,
      2147483647
    )
  FROM LabUsersAdjusted lu
  GROUP BY LabID
)
, SelectedLab AS (
  /* (the crucial part) get one of the (currently) incomplete labs
     where the new user is being added:
     - exclude every lab whose set of users is going to match that
       of any existing full lab;
     - prioritise remaining labs by:
       1) the number of users: more users = higher priority;
       2) the order of addition: older labs (those with lower IDs)
          = higher priority;
  */
  SELECT TOP 1 LabID
  FROM UsersGrouped new
  WHERE NewUserCount = 1
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM UsersGrouped old
      WHERE new.LabUsers = old.LabUsers
        AND old.OldUserCount = @maxUsers
    )
  ORDER BY
    OldUserCount DESC,
    LabID        ASC
)
/* merge the selected lab into the existing lab set */
MERGE INTO Labs
USING SelectedLab s ON (Labs.LabID = s.LabID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN  /* if there's a match, just do nothing */
  UPDATE SET @zone = @zone
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN  /* when no match, add a new lab */
  INSERT (LabName, LabZone) VALUES (@defLabName, @zone)
/* in any event, remember the final LabID */
OUTPUT INSERTED.LabID INTO @SelectedLab (LabID)
;
/* add the new user as a member of the stored LabID;
   if no LabID was OUTPUT by MERGE, then @SelectedLab
   contains no rows and, consequently, no user gets inserted */
INSERT INTO LabUsers (LabUserName, LabID)
SELECT @userName, LabID FROM @SelectedLab
;
/* return the remembered LabID or 0 */
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT LabID FROM @SelectedLab), 0) AS Result;
```

For the above example and specified parameter values, the script returns `0`. Play with arguments and/or pre-inserted data to see other results.